# How to Import Data from Ms access table to sql server table

Tags: sql, vb6

I have one table, Checkinout in Ms Access, and I want to import all the data of that table to my SQL Server database Checkinout table, using VB 6.0:

This is my code. It is not working perfectly [is this irony?]

```
   For i = 1 To LstLog.ListItems.Count
       For j = 1 To LstLog.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
           REC.Open "insert into xyz (EmpID, LogID,CheckTime,SensorID) Values ('" & _
               LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & _
               LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & _
               LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & _
               LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "' )", CN, _
               adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
       Next j
   Next i
```

Comment: I think you can create ODBC connections to each database and then use them in your program to transfer data from one to the other... But I must ask, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the same sub item id. Drop the inner for loop, e.g.:

```
For i = 1 To LstLog.ListItems.Count
    REC.Open "insert into xyz (EmpID, LogID,CheckTime,SensorID) Values ('" & _
        LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(1) & "','" & _
        LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(2) & "','" & _
        LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(3) & "','" & _
        LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(4) & "' )", CN, _
        adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DBConvert` for this purpose.

DBConvert for Access and MySQL migration tool converts Microsoft Access to MySQL server and MySQL to Access.

You can refer this direct link for **referance:**

http://dbconvert.com/convert-access-to-mysql-pro.php?DB=1

If you want to do it programatically,

**Step By Step Approach:**

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7342-export-access-database-to-mysql

Comment: For i = 1 To LstLog.ListItems.Count
            For j = 1 To LstLog.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
            REC.Open "insert into xyz (EmpID, LogID,CheckTime,SensorID) Values ('" & LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "','" & LstLog.ListItems(i).SubItems(j) & "' )", CN, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
            
            Next j
            Next i
            
            CN.Close
            End If